# X Server segfault when starting after updating from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, xorg, amd-graphics

After updating from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, my Xserver fails to start, and spits out a segmentation fault.

I have an AMD GPU, with AMD drivers installed. Here is the XServer log:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-179-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux louvre 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic root=/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root ro intel_pstate=disable acpi=force
Build Date: 21 May 2020  08:22:15AM
xorg-server 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Jul  5 19:41:06 2020
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) amdgpu: module ABI major version (23) doesn't match the server's version (24)
(EE) amdgpu: module ABI major version (23) doesn't match the server's version (24)
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13c) [0x55e2d27b1dec]
(EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x60) [0x7f0f950bb41f]
(EE) 2: ? (?+0x0) [0x0]
(EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f0f94960830]
(EE) 4: ? (?+0x0) [0x55e2d2f663c0]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your AMDGPU video drivers need to be updated. Boot with nomodeset. Purge the old driver. Download the current version. Install it.